# Cannot install Git on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: git, 21.10

When I was trying to install Git on Ubuntu 21.10, I get an error. The command I used to install git is:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git
```

The error I encountered was:

```
$ sudo apt install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 git : Depends: liberror-perl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add the output of `apt-cache policy liberror-perl`.

Comment: Or append `liberror-perl` to your `sudo apt install git` command. Be prepared to lather, rinse, repeat until you run out of complaints.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)